# How to skew to refect-box only

Tags: css, skew, reflect

I want to add skew to the reflection part of the div only, not the whole div or text. below is the reflect-box CSS style I'm using.

```css
.reflect{
 -webkit-box-reflect: below -0.5em
  -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
        center top, center bottom,
  from(transparent),
  color-stop(0.3, transparent),
        to(white));
        
}
```

```html
   <h1 class="main_header reflect"> CooK BooK </h1>
```

Comment: Add HTML and CSS properly or create jsfiddle

Comment: *"This feature is not intended to be used by Web sites. "* I'd recommen finding another method.